# Crystal Reports RecordSelectionFormula does not work

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

It's my code:

```
CrystalReportViewer1.Zoom(75)
Dim rpt As New CrystalReport1
rpt.RecordSelectionFormula = "{members.id} ='3232'"
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

It shows all records, I don't know why

Comment: what is the sql query used by the report?

Comment: SQL query? RecordSelectionFormula is the only formula that I used, I don't know where can I find what you mentioned.

Comment: Your rpt object most probably has a 'SQLQueryString' property, which holds the SQL query sent against the database server. Could you check this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim CrReport As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
CrReport = New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument()
CrReport.Load(Application.StartupPath & "\CrystalReport1.rpt")
CrReport.SetDataSource("HERE YOUR DATASET USED IN DA DESIGN OF CRYSTALREPORT1.rpt")
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CrReport
CrReport.RecordSelectionFormula = "{members.id} ='3232'"
```

Your CRYSTALREPORT1.rpt must be located at `\\BIN\DEBUG` OF your appath and it must be almost created before. Like an object by the designer from Visual Studio... .. > ADD NEW ITEM > CR

Answer (score 1):

You must create a CrystalReportDocument in Form report (desing view), and after that, the Visual Studio will display a window where you can choose a Class for CrystalReportDocument. Choose the Class related with the report.rpt, and then in the print event add this:

```
crystalReportDocument.Load(@"reports\report.rpt");

crystalReportDocument.RecordSelectionFormula = "{viewTable.IdTable}=1";

crystalReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
```

viewTable is a view element in Data Base.

Many people are used to DATASET for all, but in many cases it's ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that you set your .recordSelectionFormula before you assign the report to the reportsource property of the viewer.

This Doesn't seem to Work

```
  CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDoc
  reportDoc.RecordSelectionFormula = "{MyField} = '1008'"

  CrystalReportViewer1.Show()
```

This woks for me.

```
  reportDoc.RecordSelectionFormula = "{MyField} = '1008'"
  CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDoc

  CrystalReportViewer1.Show()
```